# Django userena redirect after account activate

Tags: django, django-userena

I've got userena set up and working good however I cannot seem to find a setting or method to redirect the user after they activate their account via email. By default they are directed to the userena profile page (I am trying to remove this from my project's flow entirely).

I found this issue on github: https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/issues/377 however the suggested solution is not working for me (or I've done something incorrectly).

Here is the url override I have tried:

```
(r'^accounts/activate/$','userena.views.activate',{'success_url': '/myaccount'}),
```

I have also tried a slight variation:

```
(r'^accounts/activate/$','userena.views.activate',{'success_url': 'app:myAccount'}),
```

Both have had no effect and the activation link continues to send the user to the userena profile page. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could work:

```
(r'^accounts/activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$','userena.views.activate',{'success_url': '/url/to/app'}),
```